# Copy files to a directory, based on contain part of the filename

Tags: powershell, copy

I have multiple files. 
Every file have first 7 characters like:

```
*123-123* something.pdf 
*123-123* apple.pdf
*234-234* fruits.pdf
*345-232* pinnaple.pdf
```

I want to copy each file to a folder that contain part of the filename (folders already exists). Folders have names:

```
*123-123* folder one
*123-123* folder one
*234-234* something
*345-232* raps
```

The result will must be like:

```
*123-123* folder one\*123-123* something.pdf 
*123-123* folder one\*123-123* apple.pdf
*234-234* something\*234-234* fruits.pdf
*345-232* raps\*345-232* pinnaple.pdf
```

How can I do that using powershell?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: I don't have nothing yet :/

Comment: You need the following commands for your task. Please try and ask if you have any questions :-)
[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) / 
[foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-6) / 
[Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 0):

First, executed the following code , it ll create directories and files for testing purposes...or create it manually, as you wish

```
[string[]] $files= "123-123ABC.txt", "123-123XYZ.txt", "234-234ABC.txt", "345-232XYZ.txt"

if ( Test-Path  "C:\Test") 
{
    Write-host "C:\Test already exists, either delete the directory or change to another directory in the code"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    break;
}

else 
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path  C:\Test  
    $files| ForEach-Object {New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:\Test\$_}  
    $files | ForEach-Object {New-Item -ItemType Directory "C:\Test\$($_.substring(0,7))"} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

I tested it with the following line of code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -File  -Name | ForEach-Object {Copy-item -Path "C:\Test\$_"  -Destination  "C:\Test\$($_.substring(0,7))"}
```

A feedback if it works for you would be appreciated.